# How to reset the console output? Clearing just shifts the output back

Tags: rust, console-application

My console application needs to clear the screen. How do I truly clear the screen, like the reset command in Linux?

I tried using methods I found on Google, like:

```rust
print!("{}[2J", 27 as char); // First attempt
print!("{}", termion::clear::All); // 'termion' crate, version 1.5.3
```

They all just scroll down, leaving the previous output behind.  I thought of executing the reset command through Rust, but there must be some other way, right?

Comment: Please don't do this. I'd be very pissed at a program that would dare clearing my terminal. Have you considered using the [alternate screen buffers](https://docs.rs/termion/1.5.3/termion/screen/index.html) instead?

Comment: @mcarton Ohh, that's nice. I'll try that.

Comment: first comment is the best answer

Answer (score 2):

Since no one is writing an answer, I'll do.

As `@mcarton` mentioned, you need to use an `alternate screen` that will auto reset everything after going out of scope.

Basically this will create a `virtual screen` over your current `terminal screen` that will be positioned just `on` the old one at the `same coordinates` with the `same height and width`. Its like a `copy`, for short.

During your program you will write and delete to the alternate screen without harming your terminal screen.

An example working code from [`docs`](https://docs.rs/termion/1.5.3/termion/screen/index.html) is:

```rust
use termion::screen::AlternateScreen;
use std::io::{Write, stdout};

fn main() {
    {
        let mut screen = AlternateScreen::from(stdout());
        write!(screen, "Writing to alternate screen!").unwrap();
        screen.flush().unwrap();
    }
    println!("Writing to main screen.");
}
```

---

You can also use `termion` to print to the mutable alternate screen.

```rust
        write!(
            screen,
            "{}{}{}",
            termion::cursor::Goto(1, 10),
            "some text on coordinates (y=10, x=1)",
            termion::cursor::Hide,
        )
        .unwrap();
//
// to refresh the screen you need to flush it, i.e 
// to write all the changes from the buffer to the screen
// just like flushing to toilet, 
// but flushing the buffer where the text was placed
// which is a matrix
        self.screen.flush().unwrap();
```